# vue:call a function with extra param

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

https://github.com/ElemeFE/element
http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload

```
<el-upload
  class="avatar-uploader"
  action="/upload"
  :show-file-list="false"
  :on-error="handleUrlError"
  :on-success="handleUrlSuccess">
  <i v-else class="el-icon-plus avatar-uploader-icon"></i>
</el-upload>
```

function:

```
handleUrlSuccess(response, file, fileList) {
}
```

if add a extra param:

```
<el-upload
  class="avatar-uploader"
  action="/upload"
  :show-file-list="false"
  :on-error="handleUrlError"
  :on-success="handleUrlSuccess(response, file, fileList, 233)">
  <i v-else class="el-icon-plus avatar-uploader-icon"></i>
</el-upload>
```

function:

```
handleUrlSuccess(response, file, fileList, param) {
}
```

Property or method "response" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for your method are coming from the component's emitted *on-success* event. For example, it would have something like

```
this.$emit('on-success', response, file, fileList)
```

Internally, Vue would do something like (and this is very simplified)...

```
let boundEventHandler = parseEventHandlerExpression(eventName)
boundEventFunction.apply(vmInstance, arguments)
```

What you can do in your consumer is capture all these arguments and then append your own

```
:on-success="handleUrlSuccess(...arguments, 233)"
```

or

```
:on-success="(res, file, fileList) => handleUrlSuccess(res, file, fileList, 233)"
```

<sub>Thanks [woki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7223144/woki) for that last one</sub>

Comment: Error in render: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" found in

Comment: @woki Can't help you with that one without a) seeing the rest of that error message, and b) the code that it refers to

Comment: :on-success="(response, file, fileList) => {handleUrlSuccess(response, file, fileList,  233) }"